# bytes to be converted into PrivateKey Object

Tags: java, cryptography

I have a symmetric Key  in my JKS (Java Key Store) file, I want to wrap my private key with a symmetric key.

Again I am using wrappedBytes to PrivateKey Object. And finally I want the KeyPair Object.

The below code gives the following error message:

> java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=125, too big.**

```
public KeyPair wrapPrivateKeyWithSymmetricKey(KeyPair keyPair) {

    try {
        PrivateKey priv = keyPair.getPrivate();
        SecretKey symmetricKey = "bjksabfkasdbgvkasbvkkj";//symmetricKey from jks file

        //wrapping Private Key
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, symmetricKey);
        byte[] wrappedKey = cipher.wrap(priv);

        //wrappedKey bytes to PrivateKey Object
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(priv.getAlgorithm());
        EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(wrappedKey);
        PrivateKey privateKey2 = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec); //above Error Throwing in this line

        return new KeyPair(keyPair.getPublic(), privateKey2);;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Information Security Stack Exchange! I think this question is better fit for [SO]. You can flag your post for moderator attention and ask for migration. You may want to show what's in your `catch` statement, for the sake of clarity. Also, it helps to show on what line the error occurs - you can find this in the stack trace that comes with the Exception. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `wrappedBytes` isn't in a [PKCS #8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5958) format. It's simply some AES encrypted blocks—essentially random data—with no encoded structure.

If you want to create an *encrypted* PKCS #8 (formally, [`EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5958#section-3)) you'll need a library that handles that. The built-in API you are trying to use only handles its clear-text payload, [`PrivateKeyInfo`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5958#section-2) (as described in [its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/spec/PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.html)).

There isn't much to the wrapper, and you could write the necessary DER coding yourself, or use a library like [BouncyCastle.](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/pkcs/package-summary.html)

---

Here's code, using BouncyCastle to encoded and decode the `EncryptyedPrivateKeyInfo` structure. The useless class provided by the JCE doesn't work, because of poor handling of the key encryption algorithm identifier and its parameters.

```
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateCrtKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Encodable;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1OctetString;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEROctetString;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.nist.NISTObjectIdentifiers;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo;

final class PKCS8
{

  private static final ASN1ObjectIdentifier AES = ASN1ObjectIdentifier.getInstance(NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_aes128_CBC);

  static RSAPublicKey toPublic(RSAPrivateCrtKey pvt)
    throws GeneralSecurityException
  {
    RSAPublicKeySpec pub = new RSAPublicKeySpec(pvt.getModulus(), pvt.getPublicExponent());
    KeyFactory f = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return (RSAPublicKey) f.generatePublic(pub);
  }

  static byte[] encrypt(SecretKey secret, PrivateKey pvt)
    throws Exception
  {
    Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    enc.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, secret);
    ASN1Encodable params = new DEROctetString(enc.getIV());
    AlgorithmIdentifier algId = new AlgorithmIdentifier(AES, params);
    byte[] ciphertext = enc.wrap(pvt);
    return new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(algId, ciphertext).getEncoded();
  }

  static PrivateKey decrypt(SecretKey secret, byte[] pkcs8)
    throws Exception
  {
    EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo info = new PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(pkcs8).toASN1Structure();
    AlgorithmIdentifier id = info.getEncryptionAlgorithm();
    byte[] iv = ((ASN1OctetString) id.getParameters()).getOctets();
    Cipher dec = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    dec.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    return (PrivateKey) dec.unwrap(info.getEncryptedData(), "RSA", Cipher.PRIVATE_KEY);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, I am unable to find equivalent class in  BouncyCastle.  how can i get wrappedBytes into PKCS #8. can you please suggest?

Comment: Are you using password based encryption? Or are you encrypting with a randomly generated `SecretKey`?

Comment: we have one fixed Secret Key in my jks file. we are encrypting private key with Secret Key. In my example program, I am passing KeyPair object to wrapPrivateKeyWithSymmetricKey method and I am wrapping private key with Secret Key and finally return KeyPair object to the method. how can I get Private Key Object from wrappedBytes? can you please suggest?

Comment: @user3240160 Do you actually need the key encoded as a `EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo`? For example, do you need to inter-operate with some other software that requires a PKCS #8 key? You are encrypting the private key with the secret key that is protected by a password, so your private key is no safer than that password; why aren't you storing the private key in the `KeyStore` directly, as was intended? I don't want to provide code for something you don't need. You should explain *what* you are trying to accomplish, not *how* you thought you should do it.

Comment: I have KeyPair Object, I am encrypting the private key with the secret key and  required KeyPair object again.  i am persisting serialized KeyPair object into Database. can you please suggest?